# File writing : carriage return and Tab

Tags: vb6

Hi i'm new to VB6 and i want to implement this : when a user is logged he enters his name and password , i should write it in a file.

Here's the file "authentification.txt" : it has the form of username password

```
   bill hope
   jessica 1234567 
   jhon 7654321
```

Here's the code :

```
Open "c:\authentification.txt" For Binary As #1
x = txtidentifiant.Text
y = txtmotdepasse.Text
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, l
If l <> " " Then 
Put 1, i, x & vbNewLine
Put 1, i + 1, y & vbNewLine

Else
//here i want to implement a  carriage return in the file #1
End If
Loop
```

My problem is :that the file if filled like this : `bhope`
and it writes only the first line

Comment: Note that you should be thinking about a more secure method of storing both usernames and passwords

Comment: `Do While Not` is confusing negative logic.  `Do Until` is much cleaner to read.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243392%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and [Print](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266187%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) statements. They read and write comma delimited files, and are designed to be used in pairs, for just such an application.

Comment: please have you a useful link ot tutorial

Comment: There is plenty of information out there. Just do a web search for "VBA file io" or similar. VBA is a better keyword than VB6, to avoid hitting lots of VB.Net pages. The important point is that the input and output statements can be arranged in corresponding pairs.

Comment: I have updated your answer to link to the relevant pages for the Input and Print commands

Comment: Actually `Input #` is meant to be paired with `Write #` and not `Print #` statements.

Comment: Here is the correct link for `Input #`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243386(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's the new code :

```
Open "c:\authentification.txt" For Append As #1
x = txtidentifiant.Text
y = txtmotdepasse.Text
Print #1, x
Print #1, y
Close #1
```

Comment: to separate them with a tab character you can use : Print #1, x & vbTab & y

Comment: That prints x and y on two lines. If you append a semicolon to the first print statement, the output will look like the text in your example. But the main rule is that your input statements should match your print statements.